# Why did Lucas choose the word "Force"?

Tags: star-wars

The Force is more than telekinetic abilities of a Jedi or Sith.

Is there an official statement saying what motivated Lucas to choose the name "The Force" for the central idea of the canon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is covered in the book *The Secret History of Star Wars*, in an analysis of the evolution of the various draft scripts leading to the final one that we all know today.

The relevant section in chapter 2, "The Star Wars" is titled "The Force of Others" and goes on to say:

> It is interesting to note that the Force is not existent in this draft—the phrase “may the force of others be with you” is used, but it is merely a generic “good luck” phrase, and is used casually by various people in the script, as are expressions such as “thank god.” Most agree that it is a playoff of the Christian phrase “May God be with you,” intended as a sort of ambiguous science fiction version of a theistic colloquialism. When Lucas began writing the second draft he would transform the samurai-inspired Jedi-Bendu of the rough draft into characters based on E.E. Smith's Lensmen, making them super-powered warriors. In determining the source of their power, Lucas took his “force of others” reference and turned it into a supernatural power, coupled with a crystal called the Kiber crystal which acts in a similar manner to the Lensmen’s lenses, increasing one’s natural abilities.

A free sample of the book is available at http://secrethistoryofstarwars.com/book.html and the passage quoted begins on page 75.

Comment: An excellent find. Interesting stuff.